# Assign variable whilst checking it

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I'm looking for a way to assign a variable whilst it's being checked in an `if (...) { }` statement. Basically something which makes this...

```
$var = somefunction();

if ($var == 10) {
    #do something
}
```

Into something like this

```
if(($var = somefunction()) == 10) {
    #do something
}
```

As I said im not sure if this is possible but just wondered if there was a way to save assigning the variable first. I'm wanting this because I have a function which either outputs an array or false.

---

Thanks :)

Comment: `if ($var = 10)` would only check if the variable assignment succeeded or not.

Comment: @EM-Creations `if ($var = 10)` is likely the same beginner mistake that many others make.

Comment: The single = was just a typo sorry :)

Comment: @MattBall I know, but what's your point exactly? All I did is state what `if ($var = 10)` would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will also work:

```
if(($var = somefunction()) == 10) {
    #do something
}
```

but the first way you proposed is simple, clear, and readable, aside from the fact that you need to use `==` or `===`, not `=`, for equality checks:

```
$var = somefunction();

if ($var == 10) {
    #do something
}
```

Why wouldn't you just use that?

Comment: Meh, you bet me to the answer as it seems :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this would work:

```
if(($var = somefunction()) == 10) {
    //Do something
}
```

Essentially it's a matter of evaluation. Brackets get evaluated first, which is why it'll execute `$var = somefunction()` first, and then check the return value (the value of $val) against 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the variable for later use, then

```
if (somefunction() == 10) {
  //do something
}
```

will be sufficient as well.

Comment: OP specifically asked to assign memory in loop head

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
$var ;

 if (true) {
   $var= somefunction();
   if($var==10) {
      # Handler
    }
  }
```

Comment: /r/codingGore  will be pleased